# updating PS script to run daily exchange logs

Tags: powershell, csv

i create this script

```
$VarDay = (Get-Date).day
$VarMonth = (Get-Date).month

get-messagetrackinglog -Recipients:haavarot-from@my-domain.co.il -EventID "FAIL" -Start "09/20/14" -End "09/23/14" | export-csv c:\MailboxStatistics-$VarMonth-$VarDay.csv -encoding "utf8"
```

to create CSV file with the date name for FAIL mails from mail box 
its work fine 
but the only problem i cant found is to way to make it run daily wit no need to edit the DATES in the Ps code

-i want it to sat auto run at 22:00 every day and make the log for the some day only for 7 days 
in the 8 day i want it to delete the old and create a new one

i need to save only the last 7 days

and idea?

Comment: it's powershell. you can have powershell generate the dates dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

`-Start` and `-End` accepts `[System.DateTime]` so you can just use Get-Date and play with the days using `AddDays()`
Straight from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays(v=vs.110).aspx). You could do something like this

```
$endDate = Get-Date # This is today
$startDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7) # This is 7 days ago
```

If you would feel more comfortable with just the date and drop the time you can use the `.ToString()` method to format the time. *Note* that the datetime object would be lost as this returns a string.

```
$endDate = (Get-Date).ToString("MM/dd/yy")
$startDate = ((Get-Date).AddDays(-7)).ToString("MM/dd/yy")
```

More information on formatting dates can be found [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692801.aspx)

Comment: ok thanks :) i will tray it tommarow .its will run automatic?

Comment: This will make it so you dont have to hard code dates in your script.

Comment: You would need to look into how to make a script into a [scheduled task](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/42e7898f-b888-496a-bd37-2a87de0e27d9/scheduled-powershell-task).

Comment: hi again i use you code u add but i not found the way to make it for the some day.in my code i have the -start and -end string they tells the Ps witch date/time to run . how can i make it auto select the some day start time 7:00 end time 20:00 for every day.the 7 days code not good for me , i just use the schedule to create each day running and the Ps create me new file for every day.

Comment: this is the changes i made to the code and its looks like it work :)




$VarDay = (Get-Date).day 
$VarMonth = (Get-Date).month
$startDate = ((Get-Date)).ToString("MM/dd/yy") 

get-messagetrackinglog -Recipients:haavarot-from@altshul.co.il -EventID "RECEIVE" -start $startDate -End "22:00" | export-csv c:\MailboxStatistics-$VarMonth-$VarDay.csv -encoding "utf8"